# How to resolve Crystal Report version conflict and make them work side-by-side?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-10

I have VS-2005 and VS-2010 installed. As Crystal Reports is available as a separate download for VS-2010, I downloaded it and installed. My old projects were in VS-2010 which uses Crystal Reports version 10.0. New projects are in VS-2010 whose Crystal Reports version is 13.0.

I made a small application in VS-2010 with a single report. When I try to run this project, it displays errors:

```
The type 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' exists in both 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\10.2.3600.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll' and 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll'

The indirectly-referenced assembly 'BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' could not be found. This assembly is not required for analysis, however, analysis results could be incomplete. This assembly was referenced by: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll.
```

I can't uninstall old Crystal Reports (i.e., version 10). How to make these work side-by-side and what changes are required in **GAC** and **web.config** files.

Comment: I was also getting the same error, what I had to do is just remove the reference and also remove crystal report dlls from bin folder...then add reference to Crystal Report Engine 13.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://forums.asp.net/t/1671748.aspx/1) with Crystal Reports. It doesn't do well with side-by-side versions in the GAC.

From [SAP](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56787567):

> As each version of Crystal Reports has its' own specific runtime which
>   must be correctly deployed, it is critical that the deployed runtime
>   be in agreement with the Crystal Reports assemblies for Visual Studio
>   .NET referenced in your project.

Use `gacutil /u /f` to forcefully uninstall the older Crystal Reports assemblies.

If it doesn't let you must uninstall Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2005.

You can still keep side-by-side projects by copying the assemblies to a shared folder (e.g. '..\3rdParty\10.5.3700.0' and do a file reference to that folder instead of the GAC. 
The trick is to copy the Crystal Reports assemblies from the GAC via commnadline:

```
> copy c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine\10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll c:\dev\3rdParty\10.5.3700.0
```

To discover which assemblies are deployed:

```
gacutil /l
```

Then you simply uninstall the copied assemblies from the GAC.

Comment: What is the full syntax to uninstall old Crystal Reports assemblies? Will the old reports in VS-2005 run or not?

Comment: I don't have it installed, but AFAIR it is `gacutil /u /f CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine`, use `gacutil /l` to list all deployed assemblies

Comment: Is it going to impact my old project and reports?